# virtual host opening localhost

Tags: macos, apache, laravel, virtualhost

I am trying to setup a laravel project. I created the virtual host. But it takes to my localhost. I have googled it but couldn't find any solutions.

this is how my vhost.conf looks like

```
# Virtual Hosts
#
# Required modules: mod_log_config

# If you want to maintain multiple domains/hostnames on your
# machine you can setup VirtualHost containers for them. Most configurations
# use only name-based virtual hosts so the server doesn't need to worry about
# IP addresses. This is indicated by the asterisks in the directives below.
#
# Please see the documentation at
# <URL:http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/vhosts/>
# for further details before you try to setup virtual hosts.
#
# You may use the command line option '-S' to verify your virtual host
# configuration.

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@dummy-host2.example.com
    DocumentRoot "/usr/docs/dummy-host2.example.com"
    ServerName dummy-host2.example.com
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/dummy-host2.example.com-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName test.dev
    ServerAlias www.test.dev
    DocumentRoot "/Users/Aasim/Sites/test"
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/apple.com-error_log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/apple.com-access_log" common
    ServerAdmin web@coolestguidesontheplanet.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and this is what i added in host file

```
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1   localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
127.0.0.1 test.dev www.test.dev
```

Also i have edit the /etc/apache2/httpd.conf and /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf files 
and uncommented these lines

```
LoadModule vhost_alias_module libexec/apache2/mod_vhost_alias.so
Include /private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

and restarted the appache as well

this is what my final result is

[image]

I am using mac el capitan

Answer (score 0):

Change this line

```
  DocumentRoot "/Users/Aasim/Sites/test"
to
 DocumentRoot "/Users/Aasim/Sites/test/public"
```

Comment: What is your project location.. wamp/www/ ??

Comment: /Users/Aasim/Sites/